# weird internet connectivity issue

Tags: networking, router, usb, internet

I have dual boot system. using an internet connection which automatically disconnects for few minutes then connects back on work for 10-20 seconds and then disconnects for another few minutes.
Same issue in both OS (windows 11 and ubuntu 22.04)

I have tried restarting the router and system, changed ethernet, switched to wifi and usb tethering same issue with all the methods.

Interesting thing is same internet is working on my other devices without this issue.

Even the internet works on my usb tethered phone on same network but somehow when the internet is shared to this desktop it shows the same behaviour, another interesting fact is it works perfectly fine if i switch to another internet source, like my mobile data if same usb tethering is using my mobile data it works perfectly fine if i switch my phone to wifi, internet works in my phone perfectly, but connection to my desktop is very irregular.

Can some explain what could be the cause of this ?

I have also tried disabling and enabling IPV6.

and issue is not of DNS cause even pinging the direct ip also doesn't work.

i can also access the router's setting page through my desktop when internet is not working on my desktop, so i have proper connection to router and router have the proper connection to internet as other devices can connect to internet.

It is somehow blocking the desktop intermittently from accessing the internet, I don't know how the router is identifying my desktop and blocking it, Since MAC address should be changing when i switch from Ethernet, to WiFi and to USB tethering.

After Three different MAC addresses, two different operating system, several restarts and multitude of debugging i couldn't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Your testing has been good, including trying two different OS, which leaves not much but PC internal  hardware, I believe.  If you have access to a USB WiFi adapter (or want to buy one, some are less than US$10), it might be worth a try testing, or the issue could be at a lower level of hardware.

Comment: By the way it's working now, I had contacted my ISP, They couldn't figure it out either. I asked them to replace the router and it's working now. I still couldn't figure out the reason, But that issue was baffling